# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error con TDAs

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para la universidad y me han pedido que varias de las funciones que tengo en el main.c las pase a un TDA propio. Lo he hecho para el struct Bala.

En el main.c tengo un struct Nodo que usa dicha el struct Bala. Antes de pasar todo lo referido al struct Bala al TDA me funcionaba todo perfectamente, pero ahora me da error en todas las funciones en las que intente acceder al elemento Bala del struct Nodo, aunque si he incluido el .h del TDA en el main.c

Dejo aquí los códigos:

```
struct BalaRep{
double x;
double y;
double h;
double w;
double vx;
double vy;
Imagen ImBala;};
```

En el .h del TDA tengo esto:

```
typedef struct BalaRep * Bala;
```

Luego en el main.c:

```
struct Nodo{
Bala b;
struct Nodo*sig;};

typedef struct Nodo * NodoPtr;

void dibuja_rafaga(NodoPtr cabecera){
NodoPtr aux=cabecera;
while(aux->sig!=NULL){
    aux=aux->sig;
    Pantalla_DibujaImagen(aux->b->ImBala,aux->b->x,aux->b->y,aux->b->w,aux->b->h);
};};

void libera_bala_rafaga(NodoPtr cabecera){
NodoPtr borrar=cabecera->sig;
cabecera->sig=borrar->sig;
Pantalla_ImagenLibera(borrar->b->ImBala);
free(borrar);};

void mueve_rafaga(NodoPtr cabecera){
NodoPtr aux=cabecera;
while(aux->sig!=NULL){
    if (aux->sig->b->y < 0 || aux->sig->b->y > 720 || aux->sig->b->x < 0 || aux->sig->b->x >1280){
        libera_bala_rafaga(aux);
    };
    if(aux->sig!=NULL){
    aux=aux->sig;
    Mueve_Bala(aux->b);
    };
}; };
```

Cuando pulso en el error no me marca ninguna línea en específico si no que siempre me manda al final de las funciones, pero el número de errores en cada función siempre es el número de accesos al elemento bala del struct Nodo que ocurre en dicha función, así que supongo que el error estará ahí

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿En qué línea te sale el error? ¿Dónde esta la definición del struct? ¿Qué archivos *include*s en el `main.c`? Puedes pulsar el botón de Editar para actualizar la pregunta

Comment: Y se supone que solo leyendo ese codigo vamos a saber cual es el error? Ayudanos a que te ayudemos, y trae un [ejemplo minimo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Eso significa que de el codigo que tu publicaste, yo tengo que poder copiar, pegar, y reproducir tu problema. Con lo que nos has colocado de momento es imposible.

Comment: @SJuan76 no me dice exactamente en que línea me sale el error. Cuando pulso el error siempre me manda al }; del final de las funciones, aunque ya que el error me pasó al pasar la estructura bala al TDA supongo que será en los accesos al struct Bala desde el struct Nodo

Comment: @Pablochaches el problema es que tiene funciones que provienen de un TDA que nos pasó nuestro profesor para poder manejar la creación de pantallas para el proyecto, y es bastante largo tanto el .c como el .h, por lo que pasarlo todo sería dificil

Comment: Leiste lo que te coloque sobre el ejemplo minimo?